# How to prevent page break in using \newgeometry

Tags: geometry

Is available to use newgeometry command with nopagebreak?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=5cm,right=5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-15]
\newgeometry{left=5cm,right=5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm}
\textcolor{red}{\lipsum}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot use `\newgeometry` without a page break, but depending on your overall goal, other solutions might be found.  What is your overall goal?

Comment: In my persian project I have to use \reversemarginpar.In some environments my contents go out of paper.for example in two column environments created by adjmulticolumns{2}.I've tried \ifoddpage too but it does'nt work.

Comment: Is it possible to edit your question to provide an additional MWE showing that problem?